# reset std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point to past

Tags: c++, time, c++-chrono

Is it possible to initialize a std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point variable, so that a comparison with `std::chrono::hour>(currentTime - variable)` would be greather than one?

Comment: Yes, with your second invocation, or simply `std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point var{}`. What is the issue?

Comment: Note that the zero-point of the steady clock is not a well-defined value (unlike the zero-point of `system_clock` in C++20). `steady_clock`'s epoch is not defined and is therefore variable across implementations. The only thing you're guaranteed is that it never decreases between calls to `now`.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, it is initialized so already, by using the means of default constructor.

To check, if it is "zero", you can use this:

```
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> time;
bool isInvalidTime = !time.time_since_epoch().count(); // should be true
if (isInvalidTime)
    time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
```